# Как пройти по периметру прямоугольной матрицы за один цикл?

Tags: c, массивы, алгоритм, матрицы

Как пройти по периметру прямоугольной матрицы за один цикл?

Comment: Используйте индекса крайних ячеек как вариант. Добавьте свои наработки (свой код), иначе вопрос скорее закроют как учебный

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Вот здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/761797/182825 я приводил реализацию "кольцевого итератора" для матрицы. Такой итератор позволяет пройти по кольцу в матрице (в т.ч. по периметру) "за один цикл".

Answer (score 2):

```
// c#
int[,] m = new int[w, h];
// fill matrix m
for (int i = 0; i < 2 * (w + h - 2); ++i)
{
    int e = i < w - 1 ? m[i, 0]
          : i < w + h - 2 ? m[w - 1, i - w + 1]
          : i < 2 * w + h - 3 ? m[2 * w + h - 3 - i, h - 1]
          : m[0, 2 * (w + h - 2) - i];
    // do something with element e
}
```